# Not Entering Values into the database

Tags: php

```
mysql_query("insert into user_info(Name,Id,Password,Email,Gender,Date_of_birth) values('".$name."','".$iden."','".$pass1."','".$email."','".$gender."','STR_TO_DATE('$date','%d,%m,%Y')')");
```

Can anyone tell which part of this code is incorrect, as it is not entering anything in the database.....

Comment: Just do basic debugging. Use `mysql_error()` to find out what goes wrong. The manual on `mysql_query()` shows how in the code example: http://php.net/mysql_query (Also note that the `mysql_*` family of functions is deprecated, the manual has more info on that in the red section)

Comment: Put graves around the column names, I'm thinking that `Name` is reserved.

Comment: @Pekka웃 from where do people copy that long describing mysql_* deprecating comment?

Comment: @itachi I think there are some generic ones around - the one above is not copied though, just made it up on the spot

Answer (score 1):

Unquote the `'STR_TO_DATE('$date','%d,%m,%Y')'` call. I also cleaned up the rest of the code a bit. As a result you get:

```
mysql_query("insert into user_info(Name,Id,Password,Email,Gender,Date_of_birth) values('$name','$iden','$pass1','$email','$gender',STR_TO_DATE('$date','%d,%m,%Y'))");
```

Answer (score 1):

On this part:

```
'STR_TO_DATE('$date','%d,%m,%Y')'
```

There are single quotes inside single quotes, causing an error. To fix this, replace the single quotes on the arguments to escaped double quotes, like this:

```
'STR_TO_DATE(\"$date\",\"%d,%m,%Y\")'
```

However, since you probably want to use the function and not post it literally, you should just remove the outside quotes, like this:

```
STR_TO_DATE('$date','%d,%m,%Y')
```

Comment: I said that on the last part of my answer. I just said about the escaped double quotes in case he actually wants to use it literally and to help someone who may come here with the same problem. PS: sorry for bad english

Comment: I probably should just not sleep while reading. Sorry ;-)

Comment: It's okay :P sorry if I sounded rude or something like that.